# How to show the dropdown in datatable where user can select the option to show number of rows to display on the page

Tags: jquery, html

I want to show a dropdown so that user can select the number from option list and that much rows will be displayed accordingly. In my case everything working perfectly but that dropdown is not shown at all. Thanks for the help in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#tableId').DataTable( {  
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
  buttons: [
  {
            extend: 'csv',
            exportOptions: {
            columns: [0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8]
  }
 }, 
 ]
 } );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

@lokesh
you missed to include "length" in dom option which is indicated by "l".
Change: **dom: 'Bfrtip'**  to **dom: 'Blfrtip'**

https://jsfiddle.net/0n3p8dcx/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tableId').DataTable( {      
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
    buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'csv',
        exportOptions: {
        columns: [0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8]
        }
    },  
    ]
} );
```

} );

Comment: Yes correct, but it should be 'Blfrtip' because export doesn't work when I used only 'lfrtip'

Answer (score 0):

When you create your table, you can put in any column a select control.
In this case I put a static select control but you can create and fill dynamicly your select control by a for or foreach loop.

```
<table id="tableId" style="width:100%">
 <tr>
   <th>Country</th>
   <th>City</th> 
   <th>Code</th>
</tr>
 <tr>
   <td>France</td>
   <td>Paris</td> 
   <td>
      <select>
         <option value="33">33</option>
         <option value="49">49</option>
         <option value="90">90</option>
      </select> 
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Germany</td>
  <td>Berlin</td> 
  <td>
        <select>
         <option value="33">33</option>
         <option value="49">49</option>
         <option value="90">90</option>
      </select> 
  </td>
</tr>
```